# getting dependent modules (shared objects) for a binary

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, tcl

I have a binary file on linux .. tclsh8.4. It depends on certain tcl*.so files.

1. Is there a way to get this information from the binary file itself?
2. The tcl*.so files on which the binary tclsh8.4 depends is in some other directory having limited permission. What should I do to the binary file in order to use the same .so files from some other location?

Would just copying oved .so files in the same location work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ldd` for this.

Copying the shared objects over would not work since the Linux loader only look for shared objects in directories specified in `/etc/ld.so.conf`. You would need to use `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to tell the loader where to find extra shared objects.

Comment: thank you , ldd solved the problem. I will try adding LD_LIBRARY_PATH to see if it fixes this ssue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

To see the dependencies of dynamic .so file you can use the `ldd` command. To get info about the executable file, check the `readelf` command.

If you need to check the dependencies of multiple .so files, you can use the next script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# dependencies.sh

# Needs to specify the path to check for .so dependencies
if [ $# -ne 1 ] 
then
   echo 'You need to specify the path'
   exit 0
fi

path=$1

for file in "$(find $path -name '*.so')"
do
   ldd $file
done

exit 0
```

I hope it helps.